# Is there a way in Regex Expressions to check whether a certain word appears in a string in one of two defined places?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a string, for example: `myString = "word1 word2 word3"`. I want to create a regex expression to check whether word3 comes in the place of word1 or word3. I tried using the question mark (optional), but that matches even if the string contains no occurrences of the word. I want the word to be in the string, in one of two places (word1 and word3 for example). Is there any way to do this? I am not very good with Regex expressions, any help would be appreciated.

```
str = "word3 word1 word2"  # Should match
str2 = "word3 word2 word3"  # Should not match
str3 = "word1 word3 word2"  # Should not match
str4 = "word1 word2 word2"  # Should not match
```

str4 matches when I use `"(word3)? [\w\s] (word3)?"`. Any help would be wonderful. Thank You in advance!

Comment: is your word3 always constant ?

Comment: (\w*|word3)\s(\w*)\s(\w*|word3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have addressed a more general question: given a string containing two or more words, verify the first or last word is `word3`, the first and last words are not both `word3` and there are no spaces at the beginning or end of the string. If it is necessary to confirm the string contains three words, a separate check must be done, such as `r"^\w+(?: +\w+){2}$"`.

You could use the following regular expression.

```
r"^(?:word3 (?!.* word3$)|(?!word3 ).* word3$)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rv4lEU/4/) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\_(ツ)_/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python demo](http://tpcg.io/XYjnsbzj)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                match beginning of line
(?:              begin non-capture group
  word3[ ]       match 'word3' followed by a space
  (?!.* word3$)  the space is not to be followed by ' word3' at
                 the end of the line
|                or
  (?!word3 )     do not match 'word3 ' at the beginning of the line
  .*             match 0+ chars
  [ ]word3$      match ' word3' at the end of the line 
)                end non-capture group
```

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead. In the above I've replaced two spaces with `[ ]` lest they appear to be missing.

Comment: All the answers were helpful, but your answer also helped me understand Regex Expressions better. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: There is not "ONE" way to answer a question. But, an answer with a detailled explanation is always the best. Thumbs up :-)

Answer (score 1):

Regex Try `(?m)^(?:(word3)\s+\w+\s+(?!\1\b)\w+|(?!word3\b)\w+\s+\w+\s+word3)$`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLCXFg/1)

Answer (score 1):

If word3 could only come in the first place or the third place and the word in between can be any word characters, one option is to use a negative lookahead `(?!` with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for both scenario's.

```
^(?:word3 \w+ (?!word3$)\w+|(?!word3 )\w+ \w+ word3)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `word3 \w+`  Match `word3` space 1+ word chars and space
  - `(?!word3$)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not word3 followed by end of string
  - `\w+` If the previous asserting is true, match 1+ word chars
  - `|` Or
  - `(?!word3 )` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not word3 followed by a space
  - `\w+ \w+ word3` Match 1+ word chars, space 1+ word chars space and `word3`
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XVLnF5/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gdJIu0)

*Example code*

```
import re

strings = [
    "word1 word2 word3",
    "word3 word1 word2",
    "word3 word3 word2",
    "word3 word2 word3",
    "word1 word3 word2",
    "word1 word2 word2"
];

pattern = r"(?:word3 \w+ (?!word3$)\w+|(?!word3 )\w+ \w+ word3)"
r = re.compile(pattern)
for s in strings:
    print (bool(r.match(s)))
```

*Output*

```
True
True
True
False
False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your question can be done using `str.split()` and list unpack like this example:

```
import re


myString = "word1 word2 word3"
regex = r'({2}\s{0}\s{1})|({0}\s{1}\s{2})'.format(*myString.split())
str = "word3 word1 word2"
str2 = "word3 word2 word3"
str3 = "word1 word3 word2"
str4 = "word1 word2 word2"

for elm in [myString, str, str2, str3, str4]:
    print(elm, bool(re.match(regex, elm)))
```

Output:

```
word1 word2 word3 True
word3 word1 word2 True
word3 word2 word3 False
word1 word3 word2 False
word1 word2 word2 False
```